# Remove a vector from another vector

Tags: r

I would like to remove from the vector `wine` below the vector `b=c(1,0)`.
The result should be `d=c(1,1,0)`.

```
library(gtools)

wine=c(1,1,1,0,0)
x=combinations(5,2,v=wine,set=FALSE,repeats.allowed=FALSE)
y=matrix(NA,nrow(x),3)
```

I want to find the complementary matrix `y` of `x`.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't understand what `combinations` has to do with the problem description.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The following uses a function I have posted here. The function finds where in `y` the vector `x` occurs returning an index vector into `y`.

First, get where `b` occurs in `wine`. Then the location is used to remove the found vector.

```
occurs <- function(x, y) {
  m <- length(x)
  n <- length(y)
  candidate <- seq.int(length = n - m + 1L)
  for (i in seq.int(length = m)) {
    candidate <- candidate[x[i] == y[candidate + i - 1L]]
  }
  candidate
}

wine <- c(1,1,1,0,0)
b <- c(1,0)

i <- occurs(b, wine)
d <- wine[-(i + seq(b) - 1L)]

d
#[1] 1 1 0
```